# How to solve second order ODE containing exponential function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I consider the ordinary differential equation of the form:
\begin{equation}
y''(x) + a y'(x) + (b e^{\lambda x} + c) y(x) = 0.
\end{equation}

In the book 'Handbook of Ordinary Differential Equations: Exact Solutions, Methods, and Problems' (by Andrei D. Polyanin and Valentin F. Zaitsev) on the page 585/1487 there is written a solution to this equation of the form:
$$
y=e^{−ax/2}[C_1 J_\nu(2\lambda^{−1}\sqrt{b} e^{\lambda x/2}) + C_2 Y_\nu(2\lambda^{−1}\sqrt{b} e^{\lambda x/2})], 
$$
where $\nu = \lambda^{−1}\sqrt{a^2 − 4c}$ and $J_\nu(z)$ and $Y_\nu(z)$ are Bessel functions.

The form of this soluton it's not too complicated, so I think that the way of solving this ODE is also not very difficult.

Can anyone suggest me how to derive this solution?

Comment: This substitution is far from obvious if you don't know the solution beforehand, but I believe if you make the variable transformation $u=2\lambda^{-1}\sqrt{b} e^{\lambda x/2}$ and $z=ye^{ax/2}$, then you should obtain by the chain rule
$$u^2 z''(u)+u z'(u)+(u^2-\nu^2)z(u)=0,$$
which has general solution $z(u)=C_1 J_{\nu}(u)+C_2 Y_{\nu}(u)$.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I applied these substitutions and I obtained the equation you wrote for $z(u)$. I am still curious how to solve this equation without the information about the solution.